# Why does the ValueTuple.Create 8-tuple overload wrap the last parameter in another ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, .net-core, language-design

Looking through the source code (decompiled using JetBrains Rider 2019.1.2) of [`System.ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.0) I noticed that the method that creates an 8-tuple wraps the last parameter in a tuple of its own. What is the point of wrapping an element in a 1-tuple?

```cs
public static ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<T8>> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(
    T1 item1,
    T2 item2,
    T3 item3,
    T4 item4,
    T5 item5,
    T6 item6,
    T7 item7,
    T8 item8)
{
    return new ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<T8>>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, ValueTuple.Create<T8>(item8));
}
```

Decompilation header:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.ValueTuple
// Assembly: System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
// MVID: CE11CF72-ED8D-4122-8743-9D6985631221
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0-preview3-27503-5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Comment: What if you need more than 7 items in your tuple? What if you need 10 items? It would be cumbersome for the C# maintainers to add an arbitrary number of items to the `Tuple` class.

Comment: @KennethK. I totally understand your point, but the question was about why does it wrap the last parameter in a ValueTuple, effectively creating an unnecessary 1-tuple.

Comment: Well, again, it would be cumbersome to implement an overload that has `T8` be the various flavors of `ValueTuple`. Think about what `T8` can be. It can be a `ValueTuple<T1>`, a `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, a `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3>`, etc.  It can even be a `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<T8>>`.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes, it can be, but if I call the `Create` method with `T8` as `ValueTuple<U, V>` for example, then the return value would be `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<ValueTuple<U,V>>>`. So the last element of the tuple is a 1-tuple that contains my 2-tuple.

Comment: @mjwills What's the point of that, when the other 7 type parameters can be reference types?

Comment: If you feel this strongly, have you considered calling the constructor instead? https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/ValueTuple.cs#L1964

Comment: The constructor enforces the same constraint, that the last type parameter has to be a `ValueTuple`. I understand how to create an arbitrary n-tuple, what I don't understand is the language designers' reason for the constraint on the constructor; what is the advantage of enforcing such a constraint?

Comment: `The constructor enforces the same constraint, that the last type parameter has to be a ValueTuple` It doesn't wrap it though (thus different to `Tuple.Create`). Basically a `ValueTuple` has 7 elements and a `Rest` which is another `ValueTuple`. You seem to be asking 'why can't I have 8?' but that does not solve anything. What about 9? 10? 11? 12? You have to draw a line somewhere.

Comment: I suspect part of the reason that `Tuple.Create` acts the way it does is to make it 'easy' to call (e.g. can pass in `string`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194600/discussion-between-emanuel-vintil-and-mjwills).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ValueTuple` is a type with the ability to store 7 values and say 'and I will put the leftovers in another ValueType here' (i.e. the `Rest` property).

> I still don't understand what is the advantage of wrapping the last
>   parameter in another ValueTuple. For example, why not force the
>   programmer declare a custom type and use it instead?

For two reasons:

a) If you do that, you effectively went from 7 to 8 types / values. But that doesn't solve the problem. What about 9? 10?

b) Having `Rest` be `ValueType` means you can support as many types as you want. And the code that deals with the first 7 can be the same as the code that deals with the next 7 etc etc. Since it is `ValueType` all the way down.

*Also, note that if you already have a `ValueType` as the eight parameter, call the constructor rather than `Tuple.Create` (to avoid wrapping the `ValueTuple` in **another** `ValueTuple`).*